# Using SSM from Lambda function to execute a python script on an EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-lambda, aws-ssm

I am using lambda function to invoke a python script located inside of the windows EC2 machine. When I try to execute it within powershell: set-location -path {the path of the python scripts}; python myfile.py it works fine.

When I try to do it via ssm, python is not getting recognized. I did add python to the path variables.

code:

```
response = ssm_client.send_command(
            InstanceIds=['i-*********'],
            DocumentName="AWS-RunPowerShellScript",
            Parameters={'commands': [f'set-location -path {path}; python myfile.py']}, )
```

error: the term python is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.

Can someone let me know how to do it via SSM that is making python recognizable. I did not keep the rest of the boto3 code but I did create the client and all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `Parameters={'commands': [f'set-location -path {path}; \"python myfile.py\"']}, )`

Comment: @Paolo I am getting Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': unexpected character after line continuation character.